# Does more ATP present mean that a microbe can ferment more and decrease the pH?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, fermentation

I noticed that EMP produces 2 ATP and EDP produces 1 ATP. Does that mean that if more ATP is present that would give more energy for fermentation and lowering the pH of a system?

Comment: You need to explain clearly what you are talking about, avoiding abbreviations. Why do you think fermentation *requires* energy? What type of microorganism are you concerned about? What is the relevance of the pH? At the moment your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: I'm thinking about the oral community and if utilizing the Embden–Meyerhof–Parnas Pathway more than the Entner–Doudoroff pathway could result in a lower pH.

Comment: To repeat, why do you think fermentation *requires* energy? It produces it.

Comment: @David I guess he/she meant more fuel/substrate for fermentation, or more free energy to drive the process...

Comment: @O.rka An underlying question would be what is the limiting factor that would stop fermentation assuming a closed system. Or maybe the question is about the balanced pH in a chemostat when one or the other pathway is imposed?